# Zend Form Field set Validator to invalid

Tags: php, zend-framework, forms, validation

How to set Form Field to invalid from controller?

Example:

```
$form->getElement('name')->set.... Validator to FALSE
```

or something similar???

Part of code:

```
    if(....){
    $form->getSubForm('sub_form_name')->getElement('element_name')->addError('some error message');
    }


    if($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {
//Form is going to be valid and execute this statment
    }
```

i try too with: markAsError() and hasError(); but not working :(

Comment: why you set invalid filed by controller? There are validators on the form to be used for!

Comment: if ($form->isValid( null )) { //form will definetely fail if it has any validators...}

Comment: markAsError() should work. Are you sure that your if (....) is being executed as expected?

Comment: Yes i mark this element As Error but $form->isValid() is still true!??!

Comment: markAsError()  work, but i miss to set to form not subform.......

Comment: I got the same problem. I'm not able to write my own validator because it seems like there is no way to do it in a Zend way ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336877/how-to-validate-either-zend-form-element-file-or-zend-form-element-text-are-not)). I need to do some validation before running $form->isValid(). I think for now, I will go with Jose Raupp's answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use any of the addError...() or setError...() on your element it should set the validation flag to invalid, or so the documentation says

**Zend_Form_Element.addError(string $message)**

*Add an error message and mark element as failed validation*

Comment: OK, but i add Error to this element but after that i have `$form->isValid()` Validation and the element with added Error is still valid? What is wrong?

Comment: post it in question, please check

Answer (score 1):

A litle POGramation. :)
Not the best way, but works fine.

```
            $vazio = false;
        if(is_array($nomes)){
      $vazio = true; 
              $form->addError("NomeIsArray");
        }

        if(!$vazio && $form->isValid($post)){

            }
```

Comment: Actually to make it work in preferred way we should check $vazio as second one, to make ->isValid do it's work. `if(form->isValid($post) && !$vazio)` And it's dirty, but it seems like it's the only option for now in my case. +1 for hints.