# Validate form but not subform

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate, zend-form-sub-form

I have a Zend_Form whose sub-form is only required in certain circumstances.  The parent form and the sub-form both have required fields. The sub-form will not always be filled but when any of its elements are filled, they should all be filled.

```
<?php
class Cred extends Zend_Form
{

  public function init()
  {
    $title = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Title');
    $title->setLabel('Title')
        ->setRequired(TRUE);
    $this->addElement($title);

    $award = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Awarded');
    $award->setLabel('Awarded On')
        ->setRequired(TRUE)
        ->addValidator('date');
    $this->addElement($award);

    $subform = new Zend_Form_SubForm();

    $proof = new Zend_Form_Element_File('Documentation');
    $proof->setLabel('Documentation')
        ->setRequired(TRUE)
        ->addValidator('Size', false, 409600) // limit to 400K
        ->addValidator('Extension', false, 'pdf');
    $subform->addElement($proof);

    $lang = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('Language');
    $lang->setLabel('Language')->setRequired(TRUE);
    $subform->addElement($lang);

    $this->addSubForm($subform,'importForm');

    $submit = new  Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submitForm');
    $submit->setLabel('Save');
    $this->addElement($submit);


    $this->setAction('/cred/save')
        ->setMethod('post')
        ->setEnctype(Zend_Form::ENCTYPE_MULTIPART);
  }

}
```

When I call `$form->isValid($_POST)`, it validates both the parent form and the sub-form and returns errors when the subform's required elements are empty even when the sub-form itself is not required.

Other than overloading the `isValid()` function, is there any way to validate only the parent form?

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the source code the [isValid() method of Zend_Form](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/library/Zend/Form.php#L2242) you see that there is no explicit mechanism that prevents the execution of the validators on the subforms (line 2273 ff).

Anyway, If I understand your requirement "*The sub-form will not always be filled but when any of its elements are filled, they should all be filled.*" correctly then I think your problem does not necessarily have something to do with subforms per se but rather with conditional validation. This can be solved pretty easy with a custom validator: [How to validate either Zend_Form_Element_File or Zend_Form_Element_Text are not empty.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336877/how-to-validate-either-zend-form-element-file-or-zend-form-element-text-are-not)

Just keep in mind that the elements in `$context` contain only the subform elements.

Comment: I don't have a problem finding out if the subform itself is valid when it's required, as I can `$form->getSubForm('importForm')->isValid()`.  I wanted a way to validate the parent form without the subform.  If that isn't possible I can put all the parent form's fields into a subform as well. That way I can validate the two subforms separately, and the parent form will essentially be an empty container for the subforms. Clunky but functional.  Thanks anyway.